# How to create a responsive text of multiple paragraphs with border around the text?

Tags: html, css

I have a column in which I've placed paragraphs of text.

I wanted to make the texts responsive and a border around the paragraphs of text.

So my html code right now is very simple (in a div tag which is responsive):

```
<p> text here</p>
<p> 2nd para</p>
<p> 3rd para</p>
<p> 4th para</p>
```

How do I add a border around the paragraphs (single around all paras).

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add border in css on the div.  use vw or other appropriate unit for font-size

```css
div{
border:solid black .1vw;}

p{
font-size:2.5vw;}
```

```html
<div>
<p> text here</p>
<p> 2nd para</p>
<p> 3rd para</p>
<p> 4th para</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So thanks can I add padding of a few pixels to it? Px or vw? Also 0.1 vw is right? Thanks